# TinyMCE Textarea does not show content unless switch formats

Tags: drupal, tinymce

I have TinyMCE 3.4.1 in a Drupal 7 installation. Everything was working fine. Now, the text in the textarea does not show when you go to the page with the editor. You have to switch between formats (Full html or filtered htm), then the content will show up.

When I go to the page with the editor, the content "flashes" in the textarea, then does not show until I switch formats back and forth.

I have Editor CSS set to: Define CSS
CSS path is set to
%bsites/cbuilding.org/themes/hydra_cbi/css/main.css,%bsites/cbuilding.org/themes/hydra_cbi/css/cbi.css

I have these settings for both full & filtered for now.

I appreciate any help or suggestions on this.
Thanks - k

Comment: Hello, It happened on all browsers. But the problem is solved now. THanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

yes you're totally right! Tiny 3.5 cause bugs with the editor when changing text formats. I got it solved too downgrading with 3.4.9

thank

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem stems from the TinyMCE version I was using (3.4.1). Seems that there can be a conflict when using multiple editors on a page when using the Advanced Theme. All editors may use the same ID which can cause the content to show in one, but not the other.

I had two editors on the page. When I moved the one that wasn't showing content in the textarea to the top spot, the content showed.

I upgraded to TinyMCE 3.5b and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

A little warning if you use version 3.5b. We combined this version with Drupal7.12 and we had following issue: When switching between text formats (f.e. filtered and full HTML) the toolbar was broken. Every time a switch between formats was made the toolbar kept repeating itself. We downgraded to version 3.4.9 and that solved the problem. It seems that the problem of #1 doesn't appear with version 3.4.9.